# vcpkg installing of opencv failed with error : ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: c++, cmake, gtk, ninja, vcpkg

I have a project that works properly in Windows but when trying to use it in Linux (Ubnto 22.04) I am getting an error.

The environment is Ubunto 2204, CMake and VCPKG (all of them were downloaded and installed in Jan 2024, so I assume they are the latest version.

The cmakelist.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)
if (DEFINED ENV{VCPKG_ROOT})
    File(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{VCPKG_ROOT} VCPKG_ROOT)
    message(STATUS ${VCPKG_ROOT})
    if(WIN32)
        set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "")
        set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-windows-static" CACHE STRING "")
    else(WIN32)
        set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
        set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-linux" CACHE STRING "")
    endif(WIN32)
    set(VCPKG_AVALIABLE TRUE)
else (DEFINED ENV{VCPKG_ROOT})
    message(WARNING "VCPKG_ROOT is not defined, OpenCV will not be used.")
    set(VCPKG_AVALIABLE FALSE)
endif()
project (test)
if (MSVC)
    add_definitions (-D_USE_MATH_DEFINES)
    add_definitions(/MP)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Ot /openmp" )
    set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
    
endif()

set(CXX_STANDARD 20)
enable_language(C)
enable_language(CXX)

if(VCPKG_AVALIABLE)
    set(OpenCV_STATIC, ON)
    FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
    add_definitions (-D_USE_OPENCV)
endif(VCPKG_AVALIABLE)

add_executable(test main.cpp})
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

and vcpkg.json is:

```
{
    "dependencies": [
    {
        "name": "opencv"
    }
   ]
}
```

when I build the application using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmake -B./build -S./
cd build
make
```

I am getting this error:

```
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

how can I fix it?

## Edit 1

content of vcpkg-manifest-install.log:

```
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-linux...
The following packages will be built and installed:
  * flatbuffers:x64-linux@23.5.26#1
  * gtk3:x64-linux@3.24.38#1
    opencv[core,default-features]:x64-linux@4.8.0#1
  * opencv4[core,default-features,dnn,gtk,jpeg,png,quirc,tiff,webp]:x64-linux@4.8.0#15
  * protobuf:x64-linux@3.21.12#1
  * vcpkg-get-python-packages:x64-linux@2024-01-02
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Restored 0 package(s) from /home/mans/.cache/vcpkg/archives in 25.4 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/6 gtk3:x64-linux@3.24.38#1...
Building gtk3:x64-linux@3.24.38#1...
-- Using cached GNOME-gtk-3.24.38.tar.gz.
-- Cleaning sources at /home/mans/local/vcpkg/buildtrees/gtk3/src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean. Use --editable to skip cleaning for the packages you specify.
-- Extracting source /home/mans/local/vcpkg/downloads/GNOME-gtk-3.24.38.tar.gz
-- Applying patch 0001-build.patch
-- Applying patch cairo-cpp-linkage.patch
-- Using source at /home/mans/local/vcpkg/buildtrees/gtk3/src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean
-- Getting CMake variables for x64-linux-dbg
-- Getting CMake variables for x64-linux-rel
-- Configuring x64-linux-dbg
-- Configuring x64-linux-dbg done
-- Configuring x64-linux-rel
-- Configuring x64-linux-rel done
-- Package x64-linux-dbg
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:112 (message):
    Command failed: /home/mans/local/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-linux/ninja install -v
    Working Directory: /home/mans/local/vcpkg/buildtrees/gtk3/x64-linux-dbg
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      /home/mans/local/vcpkg/buildtrees/gtk3/package-x64-linux-dbg-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_install_meson.cmake:33 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/gtk3/portfile.cmake:79 (vcpkg_install_meson)
  scripts/ports.cmake:170 (include)


error: building gtk3:x64-linux failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Elapsed time to handle gtk3:x64-linux: 11 s
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+gtk3
You can submit a new issue at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?title=[gtk3]+Build+error+on+x64-linux&body=Copy+issue+body+from+%2Fhome%2Fmans%2FMyData%2FBitBucket%2Ftest%2Fvcpkg%2Fbuild%2Fvcpkg_installed%2Fvcpkg%2Fissue_body.md
```

and content of package-x64-linux-dbg-out.log

```
[1/906] /home/mans/MyData/BitBucket/test/vcpkg/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/tools/glib/glib-compile-resources gdk/gdk.gresource.xml --sourcedir ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gdk/. --sourcedir ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gdk --c-name _gdk --internal --generate --target gdk/gdkresources.c --manual-register --dependency-file gdk/gdkresources.c.d

multipress.so.p/gtkimcontextmultipress.c.o -c ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.c
../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.c: In function ‘on_timeout’:
../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.c:204:3: warning: ‘gdk_threads_enter’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  204 |   gdk_threads_enter ();
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gdk/gdk.h:61,
                 from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.h:20,
                 from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.c:20:
../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gdk/gdkthreads.h:46:10: note: declared here
   46 | void     gdk_threads_enter                    (void);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.c:214:3: warning: ‘gdk_threads_leave’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  214 |   gdk_threads_leave ();
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gdk/gdk.h:61,
                 from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.h:20,
                 from ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/modules/input/gtkimcontextmultipress.c:20:
../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gdk/gdkthreads.h:48:10: note: declared here
   48 | void     gdk_threads_leave                    (void);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[312/906] /usr/bin/python3 /home/mans/MyData/BitBucket/test/vcpkg/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-

Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=empty-body -Werror=write-strings -MD -MQ gdk/libgdk-3.a.p/gdkwindow.c.o -MF gdk/libgdk-3.a.p/gdkwindow.c.o.d -o gdk/libgdk-3.a.p/gdkwindow.c.o -c ../src/3.24.38-f430748213.clean/gdk/gdkwindow.c
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: How the software was downloaded and installed (`apt install` or something else)? Is there any other output beside `subcommand failed`? Is there a reason you cannot use prebuilt packages? Also, there is a typo in `add_executable`

Comment: @Incomputable Which software do you mean? There are some warnings, but no errors. I want to use the vcpkg so the CMake for Linux and Windows become similar to each other. The applications, CMake and vcpkg are working properly in Windows.

Comment: It definitely should be more descriptive error message, than "subcommand failed". And the error from **ninja** when you build the project with `make` looks suspicious.. it is like not the `make` run which fails.

Comment: this doesn't fail in anything "opencv", it fails in something "gtk"

Comment: @Tsyvarev Where can I find more information about the error?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It is a dependency of opencv. I need opencv in my application.

Comment: "Where can I find more information about the error?" - First you need to find out which exact command from your script causes the error. As stated in the comments above, you got the error when `vcpkg` build gtk3 package. Most likely you will be able to reproduce that problem with `vcpkg install gtk3:x64-linux`, so your CMake project is absolutely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: It generate the same error.

Comment: I was face same problem with you. I decided manual install library  by `apt` instead of handle by `vcpkg` on linux. I also use `CMakePresets.json` for create preset for each environment.

Comment: if you don't need GUI, you can disable the `highgui` module. then you won't need gtk. in any case, issue happens in gtk. I see no trace of actual opencv code causing errors.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I do not need highGUI, how can I disable it in vcpkg? I only need to be able to convert a buffer into an image and the save it